# reprex in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, reprex

I an unable to get reprex to run. Here is a copy of the console session:

```
> library(reprex)
> y <- 1:4
> mean(y)
[1] 2.5
> reprex()
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "w") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Richard.R': Permission denied
```

Note that this is on a machine I do not have admin rights for. Also `Richard` is not my userid on this machine, it is `Richard.` followed by my last name.

How can I get reprex to run normally?

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a `permission` problem.
You may not have `write` access in the current directory.
You can see your current directory with `getwd()`

Please change your current directory with `setwd()` function to any other directory where you have `write` access and retry this.

Comment: Still having this issue. No matter what directory I tried reprex always tried pointing to that same one. I then  tried with the outfile=NA and got a different error:
       > reprex(outfile = NA)
          Preparing reprex as .R file:
             * reprex5ee02ab4452c_reprex.R
          Rendering reprex…
          Error in process_initialize(self, private, command, args,
 stdin, stdout,  :
 Command not found